# GeoJSON opening hyperlink to local file in the local application instead of browser

Tags: geojson, hyperlink, windows-10, browser

I have got a GeoJSON file with link to the local file, which works.

[How to write hyperlinks to local files in GeoJSON properties?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331746/how-to-write-hyperlinks-to-local-files-in-geojson-properties/331754#331754)

Continuing the question above I would like to have this link sorted directly to the Windows instead the Google Chrome (or another browser) directory.

I found a couple solutions:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835836/html-link-to-local-file-and-open-in-local-application

But it hasn't help me so far.

For a convenient purpose, I would like to have a folder window popped up instead of the folder directory in Chrome.

Is it possible?

[image: Local folder directory opened in Chrome]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, none of the web browsers support a direct access to the local directory. The reason lies in the security policies, explained here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855614/what-are-the-ways-to-make-an-html-link-open-a-folder

In case of Chrome there are 2 plugins available:

**Local Explorer - File Manager on web browser**

and

**Enable local file links**

but the result is the same as above.

Only IE enables (so far) open it in the windows app, but also not directly.

You must right-click on your link, click "Copy link" and paste it to the new tab, then press enter.

[image]

Comment: you can accept your own answer